# structure node.js App with modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I want to structure my Node.js app with modules.
For example I use bunyan as a logger.

I have a file main.js

```
//configs
var logfile = __dirname + '/log.txt';

//my own modules
var log = require("./modules/log"),
    init = require("./modules/init");
```

So I´m passing the log file + path to the log module.

My log.js

```
var bunyan    = require('bunyan');

function init(logfile){

var log = bunyan.createLogger({
  name: "myapp",
  streams: [{
    path: logfile
  }]
});
  return log;
};

module.exports.init = init;
```

And the init.js which at the moment only catches uncaught exceptions:

```
var logging = require('./log'),
    log = logging.init;

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {

  //print to console
  console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message);
  console.error(err.stack);

  //print to bunyan logger
  log.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message);
  log.error(err.stack);

});
```

My main problem now is that I want to use the logger in every module.
But when I do

```
var logging = require('./log'),
    log = logging.init;
```

in every file then it would create the logger every time.
I just want to initialize it once and then use it in every module.

I thought about to remove the function for the logger:

log.js

```
var bunyan    = require('bunyan');
var log = bunyan.createLogger({
  name: "juntidos",
  streams: [{
    path: logfile
  }]
});
```

When I load the module it would be called only once. But how can I pass the filename parameter then?

Comment: Do you want to use multiple log files or do you want all of your modules to log to the same file?

Comment: all should log to the same file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I´m passing the log file + path to the log module.

I see that you define `logfile` before you `require` the log module, but unlike JavaScript in the browser, Node.js variables are not global by default.

Your log file path is not visible to any of your modules.

---

If you want to (1) initialize your logger so it can be used throughout your app and (2) pass in the logfile name instead of hard-coding it into your `log.js` module, one way is to do this:

```
// log.js

var bunyan = require('bunyan');

module.exports = {
    logger: undefined,

    init: function(logfile) {
        this.logger = bunyan.createLogger({
            name: 'myapp',
            streams: [{
                path: logfile    
            }]
        });
    }
};
```

Now, you just need to ensure that `init()` is called exactly once, and that this happens *before* any other modules are loaded. That should be easy enough:

```
// main.js

var logfile = __dirname + '/log.txt';

var log = require('./modules/log.js').init(logfile),    // init() called here
    anotherModule = require('./modules/anotherModule.js')
    someOtherModule = require('./modules/someOtherModule.js');
```

And in your sub-modules, do this:

```
// someOtherModule.js

var log = require('./log.js');
log.logger.warn('someOtherModule was loaded');
```